# How to transfer char* of C++ to Python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, wrapper

I'm writing the wrapper for my C++ function, which return char* value. And I should transfer it to my Python function. But it returns empty str.

```
static PyObject* key_to_bytes_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    char * buffer;  
    key_to_bytes(&buffer);
    return PyBytes_FromString(buffer)

}
```

Call in Python

```
>>> buf = key_to_bytes_wrapper()
>>> print(buf)
```

result is

```
b''
```

I know that I should hex buffer than return, but PyBytes_FromString take only char* as param. How to solve this ?

Comment: Are you certain that `buffer` actually contains anything after the call to `key_to_bytes()`?

Comment: printf("%x\n", buffer); output is 2acb770

Comment: Okay. And as a string?

Comment: Unsigned hexadecimal integer